# Find optimal distribution of repeating graphic in given frame

Tags: graphic-design, vector-graphics

I'm looking for a tool, that, given a vector graphic and a minimum distance, will find the optimal distribution of a maximum number of copies on a given frame.

This is meant to minimise material waste when printing or cutting a certain outline as often as possible with minimum material.

I am not bound to a certain OS and willing to pay for software, although open source is preferred for monetary, ideological and engineering reasons.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Could you please let us know what OS that tool should run on, and how much it might cost? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Notes:
This sounds like an irregular object packing problem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems#Packing_of_irregular_objects .

This term could be used to refine searches.

This solution - https://github.com/Jack000/SVGnest - appears to tackle your problem, including a configuration parameter for minimum distance. It also includes some links to other resources that may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, knowing the name of the problem is a great help in finding a solution!